# AppleScript to delete Users Library files and folders

Tags: applescript, automator, library

I have an AppleScript Application that works for a logged in user, but each user of this script has to edit username and run while logged in to Apple account. I have muddled about trying to script a ***logged in privileged alias***. Can this AppleScript be adapted for any Mac device user with some ***alias*** or other way to replace or adapt ***username*** so that anyone can use it without editing the AppleScript?

```
tell application "System Events"
    set deleted to POSIX file "/Users/username/Library/Caches/"
    tell application "Finder"
        delete (files of folder deleted)
        delete (folders of folder deleted)
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: See this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632885/open-users-library-folder-using-applescript

Comment: What's a "***logged in privileged alias***"?

Comment: Let’s just hope you are not tying to break the law.

Comment: @bmike, Why convert the deleted answer by E Willa to a comment? As an answer or comment is should be deleted!

Comment: Allan, yes saw that. Not sure why, but going after Caches folder as above, POSIX file operator in the script seems to block use of '= ~/Library/'. But then using root Macintosh HD results more of 'not defined'. Original Rhodes page is thus perhaps tentative: https://mrashrhodes.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/simple-delete-files-and-folders-script-applescript/ Any idea why?

Comment: E. Willa ! abiding by laws... our system permissions dictate we must be logged in to manage our connections. Stumbled on Rhodes page just after an Apple advisor helped out, so we know where that came from:)). My hope is a simple script all can share and apply to clean Caches, Cookies and Shared Application State when web gets too sticky. Cleaning those 3 folders is harmless. Reboot after for ultimate clean.

Comment: Allan: perhaps the operator(path) syntax above line 'set deleted' will work if there's a way to avoid 'variable not defined', and that 'parent' script must enable the username alias in 'deleted' script. That's where the Rhodes page gets very fuzzy. Must keep Rhodes foundation, e.g., does not interfere with edit button for these comments. Web flush, in transit, needs an automated timed repeating release interval, too. PHP adapt might even keep networks free of Troll Factory, etc (dream on). But for now, please help with alias username.

Comment: Get the current users Library folder with `path to "dlib" from user domain`  Enter that line only (as a test) in AppleScript Editor then run.  It should output something like `alias "iMac HD:Users:mark:Library:"`  Combine that with the answer below and you should be fine

Comment: @Allan, Assuming you mean my answer, there is no real need to use what you're suggesting and combining it with the code in my answer because my answer as coded already gets the alias pathname of the User's Caches folder in their Library folder for Finder to delete everything in that container. There is no need to explicitly delete files separately from folders as in the code shown in the OP if the goal is to delete everything there. The bottom line is, the code in my answer replaces all the code in the OP to achieve the same thing without needing to make the unwanted edit expressed in the OP.

Comment: @user3439894 - Combine is the wrong word...it's meant to verify that he's getting the expected result.

Comment: @Allan, Well for that matter, `set Caches to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Caches" as alias` run by itself will verify it too. :)

Answer (score 3):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will work for any logged in **User**:

```
set Caches to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Caches" as alias

tell application "Finder"
    delete every item of container Caches
    -- empty    -- # Remove the leading '--' from in front of 'empty' if you want to also empty the Trash afterwards.
end tell
```

Update to address your comment, "Your script does not run on macOS 10.13.3 native, muddled with it for an hour, sorry." **...**

Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean by "native" in "macOS 10.13.3 native", however the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown above was tested and works, as is without any modification needed, under **macOS 10.13.3** on both an **Admin** and **Standard** account, both in **Script Editor** and as an **AppleScript** *application*. The **GIF** image below is a before and after screen shot saved as an animated GIF image to show it does indeed work.

[image: Before After Image Loop]

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: Your script does not run on macOS 10.13.3 native, muddled with it for an hour, sorry.

Comment: @mark stewart, Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean by "native" in "macOS 10.13.3 native" however I've tested this under macOS 10.13.3 and it worked without issue!